# Navigation list with bullet and background color change using just css - possible?

Tags: css, html-lists

In order to properly place a bullet image on each navigation li element we normally use the *background property* to place it.

If however, we wish to, also, add a background change to the list, we should set our anchors inside li to have "`display:block;`"

Problem:
Once we add "`display:block`" to our element and we set a background color, our bullet will vanish.

What is the best way to have a menu that will:
Change the background color when the user overs it, 
but that doesn't also loose the bullet ?

**Update:**
Please take into consideration the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4PUFa/1/

k. regards

Comment: can you add an example please?

Comment: When you set `display: block`, your element will be taking 100% of its container. Try setting a width on the `a`, and giving it a `margin-left` of the size of the bullet in pixels (plus a bit extra.)

Comment: @All An example was added to the question.

Comment: I modified my answer based off your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the `background` property for list bullets. You should be using this:

```
   ul { list-style-image: url(path/yourImage.gif); }
```

which still leaves background for background work.

**EDIT**: For a right image (per your comment), I can make two possible suggestions, but only one will work for IE7, so I will offer that only:

Put the bullet in the background of the `a` tag and change the color on the `li`.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/4PUFa/3/

Comment: Yes. Sometimes getting the height adjusted well cross browser can be a pain (there is a minor variation in how the image is positioned between browers), but that is not usually an issue in getting an image that works well for all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This bullet must be placed on the right side of the element, and not on the left side, how can we change the position there? (sorry I'm used to background image solution like the one stated on listamatic);

Comment: @MEM: Traditionally bullets precede the content (are on the left). If you have special requirements, please make sure to put them in the question body, with example code. At 213 questions, you should know this!

Comment: Ahhhh. Back to the fact that you did not post all your code as MCSI commented.

Comment: @Scott, one last request I'm sorry for not say it earlier: What if we need to text color to change on hover as well ? We cannot use a:hover because if we move our mouse near the padding area, we will have the text color with the wrong background color. Please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4PUFa/5/

Comment: Control the color by using `li:hover a` instead of `a:hover`. HOWEVER, I think it works fine with `a:hover`. The problem with your fiddle was the "Result" (of the jsfiddle UI) was over the link. See http://jsfiddle.net/4PUFa/8/

Comment: @Scott the issue was still there on your sample. The issue was related with the border. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/Cq5JY/ - about your assumption telling that we should NOT use background but list-style-image, unfortunately, I disagree with that, due to cross browser issues, I believe background is still our best option.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: Once we add "display:block" to our element and we set a background color, our bullet will vanish.

I find this to be false. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/dbugger/4PUFa/

You are probably using twice the shorthand "background", and not know that this the second abckground will invalidate ALL the seeting of the first one.

Comment: Without access to the code (OP has not responded to requests for examples), it could be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4PUFa/1/ `"we set our *anchors* inside li to have display:block;"`